Difference between the BN_mod_mul_reciprocal and BN_mod_mul_montgomery function groups in OpenSSL
The OpenSSL C library has two different sets of functions for performing modular multiplication quickly: BN_mod_mul_reciprocal and BN_mod_mul_montgomery. What are the differences between using either set of functions, and what are the advantages of either? Also, is there any way to use either of them to perform modular exponentiation?
